# Kendo UI angular - Grid - How to transform value?

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

How to transform values on Kendo Grid in regards of:

> - simple transformation like: *kendo-grid-column field="value | uppercase"* doesn't work
> - translation / internationalization - again *kendo-grid-column field="value | translate"* doesn't work
> - changing types from integer to string so integer can be filtered with kendo-grid-string-filter-cell which allows for search operations
>     like "contains", "startswith"

Answer (score 9):

Not sure about support out of the box of kendo, but i am using angular [pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) for this purpose. For example uppercase pipe is built-in pipe which you can use.

```
 <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Name">
         <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            {{ dataItem.name | uppercase }}
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

or date pipe

```
<kendo-grid-column field="createdDate" title="Created">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            {{ dataItem.createdDate | date:'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm' }}
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

for some sophisticated stuff like translations you can create custom pipe.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot apply direct pipes on field attribute at this point but if what you want to do is a formatting transformation. You could use the format attribute for instance to display number that have more than 2 decimals values using only 2 decimals you can used `format="{0:n2}"`  You also can find format for other types and custom format options

```
<kendo-grid-column field="length" title="Length" width="70" format="{0:n2}">
```

More information about transformations for telerik columns based on formatting here:
https://github.com/telerik/kendo-intl/blob/develop/docs/index.md