# How do I pass data fields in the Kendo UI grid through a pipe in angular 11?

Tags: angular, pipe, kendo-grid, datasource

I'm working in an Angular 11 project using the Kendo UI grid for Angular. I've been asked to pipe data for one of the columns through a custom pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'customPipe'
})
export class CustomPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(id: string): string {
    if (id === 'not found') {
      return '---';
    }
    return id;
  }
}
```

The pipe works as I am able to implement the following code and see --- when the id is 'not found' and the actual value of the id in all other cases:

```
{{ 'found' | customPipe }}<br> <!-- prints out 'found' -->
{{ 'not found' | customPipe }} <!-- prints out '---' -->
```

The problem is that with the Kendo UI grid, the data is bound to the grid from fields inside the data source, which are not members of the component class. So if 'dataSource' is the data source, and the field I want to pipe is 'file', the template code for the grid looks like this:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="dataSource" ... >
  ...
  <kendo-grid-column field="file | customPipe" ... >
    ...
  </kendo-grid-column>
  ...
</kendo-grid>
```

I get a warning in the browser console that says:

> Grid column field name 'file | customPipe' does not look like a valid JavaScript identifier.

...and this is right. It is not a valid Javascript identifier. 'file' is not a class member of the component but a field in the data source instead, and so the syntax for piping it through customPipe is not correct.

How do I pipe fields in the data source for the Kendo UI grid through a custom pipe?

Comment: The below mentioned solution works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/45191171/9033834

Answer (score 0):

You should write it like this

```html
  <kendo-grid-column [field]="file | customPipe" ... >
    ...
  </kendo-grid-column>
```

Comment: Thanks vue ang, but that doesn't seem to make a difference. Surrounding field with the square brackets ensures parent-to-child binding, but I still get the error `Property 'file' does not exist on type '***Component`.

Comment: This answer works great !!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45191171/9033834